Hacking system menu
In earlier versions of Mathematica under macOS, I could hack the file
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResrouces/Macintosh/MenuSetup.tr
so as to add the following just before the Help section of that file:
Menu["Locations", 
{
 MenuItem["$UserBaseDirectory", KernelExecute[ 
      SystemOpen[ $UserBaseDirectory] ], MenuEvaluator -> "System" ],
    MenuItem["$InstallationDirectory", KernelExecute[ 
     SystemOpen[ $InstallationDirectory] ], MenuEvaluator -> "System" ],
    MenuItem["$TemporaryDirectory", KernelExecute[ 
     SystemOpen[ $TemporaryDirectory] ], MenuEvaluator -> "System" ],
    MenuItem["NotebookDirectory[]",  KernelExecute[  
        If[
            ReplaceAll["FileName", NotebookInformation[SelectedNotebook[]]] =!=  "FileName", 
            SystemOpen[ NotebookDirectory[ SelectedNotebook[] ] ]
        ]], 
        MenuEvaluator -> "System"
    ],
MenuItem["Mathematica Documents",
    KernelExecute[SystemOpen["/Users/mine/Documents/Mathematica Documents"]],MenuEvaluator->"System"],
MenuItem["Math 421/Demo",
    KernelExecute[SystemOpen["/Users/mine/Courses/421/Demo"]],MenuEvaluator->"System"]
}],

And the effect would be to show a new item "Locations" in the main Mathematica menu bar. This provided a handy shortcut for opening some frequently used directories.
This does not seem to work with Wolfram 14.1: no new menu bar "Locations` appears.
Question: How can I make this work now?
Yes, I did clear the cache (Shift-Cmd) when reopening Wolfram.app after inserting that into MenuSetup.tr.
And yes, I am quite aware that such hacking of files in /Applications/Wolfram.app is not officially sanctioned.

I haven't tried it, but maybe look at this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/306688/howto-override-default-menus-in-14-1-with-an-edited-user-copy-of-menusetup-tr

If that addresses your issue, then maybe delete this as a duplicate.

Or maybe this is the better question/answer to reference: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/305953/mathematica-ignores-my-custom-menusetup-tr-windows-10

Yes, essentially a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/305953/mathematica-ignores-my-custom-menusetup-tr-windows-10 (even though that referred to Windows).

But I don't see how to mark my post as a duplicate, and don't see how to get to Meta to learn how to do that!

@Tapiocaweasel: I just said the same thing in a comment but added another comment that I don't know how to mark as a duplicate!

oh I'm sorry! I saw that and clicked the 'flag' button under your post, then linked the thing. I didn't even know that that automatically created that last comment of mine until I saw your reply! (first time flagging a post). I thought it would just put it in a review queue or something. wasn't trying to pile on!

don’t sweat it too much, murray. someone in the know will eventually give you instructions.
